# For which values of $\alpha,\beta$ does this series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have found the general solution for a reccurence relation:

$$z_n=\alpha(1+\sqrt{3})^n+\beta(1-\sqrt{3})^n,$$

and is asked for which values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ it converges. My first thought is that it converges for $\alpha=0$ and $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$, as $(1+\sqrt{3})^n\to\infty$ and $(1-\sqrt{3})^n\to0$, however, it seems too simple. Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which series.?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $(z_n)$ is convergent, then the sequence $(z_n-\beta(1-\sqrt{3})^n)$ is convergent for each $ \beta$. But then $(\alpha(1+\sqrt{3})^n)$ is convergent. This is the case $ \iff \alpha =0$.

Result: $(z_n)$ converges $ \iff \alpha =0$ and $\beta$ is arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

We have that for $\alpha \neq 0$

- $1+\sqrt{3}>1 \implies |\alpha(1+\sqrt{3})^n| \to \infty $

and for any $\beta$

- $|1-\sqrt{3}|<1\implies \beta(1-\sqrt{3})^n\to 0$

therefore

$$z_n=\alpha(1+\sqrt{3})^n+\beta(1-\sqrt{3})^n\to 0 \iff \alpha =0$$

otherwise the sequence diverges.

When $\alpha=0$ also the associated geometric series converges to

$$\sum_{1}^\infty z_n=\frac{\beta}{1-(1-\sqrt 3)}=\frac{\beta}{\sqrt 3}$$

Comment: You're mostly repeating what OP wrote in the question. I don't think this is very helpful. What would probably help OP is explain why the last equivalence holds.

Comment: @ArnaudD. It seems quite clear from my premise. We have 2 cases$ \alpha=0$ or $\alpha \neq 0$. In first one$ z_n \to 0$ and in the second$ |z_n| to \infty$. What should we add to that?

Comment: I mostly had in mind an explanation like the one in Fred's answer, but your comment clarifies what you intended (and it's certainly good to diversify the answers given). It's true that there isn't much to say...

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thanks anyway for your suggestion, I also think that diversify the answers is a good thing. Bye

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it is the recurrence relation: $z_{n+2}=2z_{n+1}+2z_n$, whose characteristic equation is: $x^2-2x-2=0$ and characteristic roots are: $x_1=1+\sqrt{3}$ and $x_2=1-\sqrt{3}$.

The solution $z_n=\alpha (1+\sqrt{3})^n+\beta(1-\sqrt{3})^n$ is convergent to zero if and only if its characteristic roots are satisfied: $|x_1|<1$ and $|x_2|<1$.

Since $|x_1|=1+\sqrt{3}>1$, then it implies $\alpha =0$. Since $|x_2|=|1-\sqrt{3}|<1$, then it implies $\beta \in \mathbb R$. See the [reference](https://mjo.osborne.economics.utoronto.ca/index.php/tutorial/index/1/sod/t).